# How to return ActionResult with specific View (not the controller name)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a method SendMail in the MVC Controller.This method calls other method ValidateLogin. This is the signature of the  Validate Login:

```
private ActionResult ValidateLogin(Models.ResetPassword model)
```

When I call the ValidateLogin from SendMail, this exception appears because the controller try to search a view SendMail, but I want to load the ResetPassword View:

```
Global Error - The view 'SendMail' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ...
```

This is the code of the SendMail:

```
public ActionResult SendMail(string login)
{
        return ValidateLogin(login);
}
```

How Can I override the View on the return statement?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally, this was the solution:

```
return View("ResetPassword", new ResetPassword
    {
        fields= fields
    });
```

Comment: Just a small addition: This will require that "ResetPassword.cshtml" should be locatable in the directory "~/Views/<controllerName>/". Where <controllerName> equals just the name of of the accessed controller class; like for example: TestController >> "~/Views/Test/ResetPassword,cshtml" will be accessed for loading. Don't struggle here, if you otherwise will get no content to be loaded. ;)

Answer (score 64):

```
private ActionResult SendMail(string login)
{
    return View("~/Views/SpecificView.cshtml")
}
```

You can directly point toward specific view by pointing to their location explicitly.

Answer (score 10):

The `View` method has a overload which get a string to a `viewName`. Sometimes you want to pass a `string` as a model and asp.net framework confuses it trying to find a view with the value `string`. Try something like this:

```
public ActionResult SendMail(string login)
{
   this.Model = login; // set the model
   return View("ValidateLogin"); // reponse the ValidateLogin view
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If SendMail was a POST, you should use the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern

```
    public ActionResult SendMail(string login)
    {
        ...        
        return RedirectToAction("ResetPassword", login);
    }

    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string login)
    {
        ...
        return View("ResetPassword", login);
    }
```

This will protect you from a double-post in IE

Answer (score 2):

You can return view by a name like this

```
return View("viewnamehere");
```

Comment: only if the view is coming from the same controller otherwise it will be failed to load.