# .Net MVC Controller different route name using the same cshtml as view

Tags: c#, .net, controller

In .NET MVC, I see it always follows this naming convention: RouteName in the controller and it is a view called 'RouteName.cshtml'.

My question is how can I use SAME cshtml file with different RouteName?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return ActionResult with specific View (not the controller name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359192/how-to-return-actionresult-with-specific-view-not-the-controller-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default View() method defaults to matching the Action name, but you can use the View(string) method to specify that path to your desired CSHTML, like in the following example:

```
// in action method that is *not* RouteName
return View("RouteName");
```

Comment: Thanks. Currently I ` return View(myViewModel)`, can you please tell me where can I find the API so that i can specifiy route name and model to my View?

Comment: check out the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View

what you're looking for sounds like the overload that take an argument list of (string, object) with the string argument being the view name and the object argument being your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use chunks of CSHTML with [partials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial); depending on the problem that you're trying to solve, this may be a better solution.

Can you edit your question and add more context? Why do you need to render the same cshtml from more than one ActionResult method? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have a view named About.cshtml
You have 2 action methods and both of them are using About.cshtml

So you can try

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
        var model = "view model";
        // Pass view model as the second parameter
        return View("About", model);
        }

public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
            // Not need pass view name because view name and action method name are same (About
            return View();
        }
```