# how to get Exception message when trying to display create/Edit view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have two business rules, i try to apply  :

1. user can insert a new invoice only when all  invoices are closed.
2. when an invoice is closed, the user can't Edit her.

an invoice has two states: a current, closed, paid and canceled

for this i have implemented my business logic in create methode in business layer

and when the user try to click submit button, the httppost action methode call the business code.

but i want to applay these rules in httpget  create/edit action methode, so that, when user try to click at the add button to display create/Edit view, he get an exception messages respectivly for both create and Edit

here's my code

```
   //business logic
   public AddInvoice(Invoice invoice)
   {
       var invoicesCount = Context.Invoices.Count(x=>x.State != 
       InvoiceState.Closed);//InvoiceState is enum
       if (invoicesCount > 0)
            throw new BusinessReulesException("you should close all your 
          invoices before insert");

          Context.Invoices.Add(invoice);
          Context.SaveChanges();
   }

   public UpdateInvoice(Invoice invoice)
   {
       if (Context.Entry(invoice).State == EntityState.Detached)
  Context.Invoices.Attach(invoice);

       if (invoices.State == InvoiceState.Closed)
           throw new BusinessReulesException("you can't update an closed invoices );

       Context.Entry(invoice).State =EntityState.Modified;
       Context.SaveChanges();
   }

  //controller code
  [httpGet]
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
     //how to apply business logic for catch Exception here
  }
  [httpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(Invoice invoice)
  {
      if(ModelState.isValide){
      try{
           invoiceBll.AddInvoice(invoice);
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      catch(BusinessRulesException ex){
             ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
      }
   }
}
//the same thing for update
//the rest of code
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep your code clean you can use `HandleError` built in filters. Like:

```
[HandleError(View = "Your_Error_View")]
public ActionResult Create(Invoice invoice)
{
  if(ModelState.isValide)
  {
    try
    {
       invoiceBll.AddInvoice(invoice);
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(BusinessRulesException ex)
    {
         ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

> ASP.Net MVC HandleError attribute provides a built-in exception filter. The HandleError attribute in ASP.NET MVC can be applied over the action method as well as a controller or at the global level for handle the exception in controller and action level. While creating our application, the HandleError attribute is automatically included within the Global.asax.cs and registered in FilterConfig.cs as shown below.

Few more ways how to handle errors in asp.net mvc:

> Web.Config customErrors
>
> Controller.OnException method
>
> HttpApplication Application_Error event
>
> Collect exceptions via .NET profiling with Retrace
>
> Custom middleware

**EDIT**

It can by specified on a method level and you can use different error views for every method, or you can specify one error view for whole controller.

Error data can be passed to the error view so you can display it there

Comment: i want to handle exception in get action methodes, not in post, to prevent display a create/edit methode when the exception is thrown

Comment: Of course, you can handle it in every method, GET, POST, PUT... You can specify different view for all of them, or you can use one view for whole controller, it is up to you. You can pass the data to the error view and display it there, you can use partial view. 
I like when my code is clean, so I prefere that, and ofc you can reuse most of that, Check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/handleerror-action-filter-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a separate view (e.g. `Shared/ErrorPage.cshtml`) that displays that error message that you're storing in the ViewBag. I assume that is what it is for, right?

```
<h2>You encountered an error!</h2>
<div class="flashing-red" id="ErrorMessage">@ViewBag.Message</div>
<img src="SadKitten.png">
```

Then in your action method, you want to [return that specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359192/how-to-return-actionresult-with-specific-view-not-the-controller-name) instead of the default:

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Invoice invoice)
{
    if(ModelState.isValide){
    try{
         invoiceBll.AddInvoice(invoice);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(BusinessRulesException ex){
         ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
         return View("~/Shared/ErrorPage.cshtml");  //<<<<-- this is new
    }
 }
```

Note: Rendering the original exception message thrown by your code for the end user to read [may not be the best practice](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/209.html).